# Join Excel rows in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible in excel to take a table like this:

[image]

And do something like this:

[image]

So if there are two or more people with the same address in the table, I want to join the rows writing all the name in just one cell and the common address in the other.

Comment: VBA would definitely be your best bet unless you have a very small set of data. If a small set, you could put Blv1 as a column, Blv2 as the next, and so forth, then concatenate a name on across the row. VBA still more effective and scaleable though..

Comment: They are more than 4000 names with more than 1000 address. How can I do using VBA?

Comment: See answer.. It should lay out the general idea of what to do in VBA for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psudo code to do this in VBA: (You can work out the real code). Note that this was written within the answer only so you will have to fill in the blanks but hopefully you get the general idea of cycling through each address and collecting any name that has a column matching that address.

```
dim address_on as string 'current address
dim names as string 'concatenate list of names
dim in_list_already as boolean

    For address_row = 1 to range().end(xldown).row
    'loop through addresses
        address_on = Range("Column" & address_row).value
        names = ""

        'First check if address_on is already in destination list?
        in_list_already = false
        for check_row = 1 to range("Destination").end(xldown).row
            If range("Destination Col" & check_row).value = address_on then
                in_list_already = true
                Exit for
            End if
        next

        if in_list_already = false then
            'Find all names that have this address
            for name_row = 1 to range().end(xldown).row
                If range("Address Column" & name_row).value = address_on then
                    names = names  & Range("Name Column" & name_row).value & ","
                End if
            next

            'remove last comma
            names = names.remove(Len(names)-1,1)

            'add to list
            Range("Column to insert to 1" & next_slot).value = names
            Range("Column to insert to 2" & next_slot).value = address_on 

        End if 

next
```

As you see `names = names  & Range("Name Column" & name_row).value & ","` just concatenates on to the list if there is a match.

The method above is:

1. Cycle through your data
2. Does item exist in output already? If not then do not display it (so there aren't duplicates).
3. Collect all names that have the address that you are on
4. Output results

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward to do with formulas if the records are aggregated as in the question (it's more complicated if the matching addresses are not together):

[image]

Unhiding columns to show the method:

[image]

I created two helper columns, one for the names and one for filtering.  To match the desired sequence in the question, I inserted the names helper column on the left.  The formula in A2:

```
=IF(C2=C1,A1& ", " &B2,B2)
```

Column C on mine is the Address column.  This checks whether the address in the current row matches the one in the previous row.  If not, that means it's a new address and it inserts the associated name.  If it is the same address as the previous one, it concatenates a comma and the row's name to the result in the previous row (so you can have any number of matching addresses).

The helper column D checks whether the row's address is the last for that address (i.e., the next row's is different).  The formula in D2:

```
=C2<>C3
```

After you populate the formulas down the columns, click in D1 and Autofilter from the menu.  In the D1 pulldown, deselect FALSE.  That hides all rows that aren't the last row for each address.

If you want a permanent, "clean" list, copy the desired filtered columns and paste into a new location.  Only the visible ones will be copied, as in my columns F and G, below:

[image]

You can paste while the filter is on, but if you paste into a range for which rows are hidden, some of your results will be hidden until you turn off the filter.

Comment: it's bit complicated but working ☺

Answer (score 1):

**I would like to suggest one UDF (User Defined Function), will solve the issue.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that Source Data in Range `A2:B8`.
- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in `E2`, finish 
  with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=INDEX($B$2:$B$8, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $B$2:$B$8)=0, COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8, "<"&$B$2:$B$8), " "), 1), COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8, "<"&$B$2:$B$8), 0))}
  ```
- **Copy** and **Paste** below shown code as 
  **Module**.

  ```
  Function ExtractinOneCell(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)

  Dim I As Long

  Dim xRet As String
  For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(2).Cells.Count

      If LookupRange.Cells(I, 2) = LookupValue Then
          If xRet = "" Then
              xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
          Else
              xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
          End If
      End If

  Next

  ExtractinOneCell = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 2)

  End Function
  ```
- Enter this Formula in `D2` and fill down.

  ```
  =ExtractinOneCell(E2,$A$2:$B$8,1,", ")
  ```

Comment: Mine's a bit complicated?  It's two trivial formulas.  :-)  This is kind of what I was referring to as a more complicated approach required if the matching records weren't together (but I would have done it all without any VBA).